# Not rewriting a method just to add a single line of code?

Tags: javascript, dry, subclassing

Time and time again this has happened to me: We have class `CLS` with `init` method like this:

```
init {
    // do A

    // do B

    // do C
}
```

Now, in a certain case we need to do `X` exactly between `B` and `C`. Making a subclass of `CLS` and re-writing the whole `init` method with `X` inserted there does not seem like a good solution to me (It is the opposite of DRY), Is there a better solution that hasn't occurred to me?


Please note that `A`, `B` and `C` are small code fragments doing small tweaks like adjusting the UI so it is probably not a good idea to put them in separate methods. I'm currently coding in JavaScript but I think this question applies to other PLs as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually add hooks to the parent class, where we expect extensions. I don't remember what it is called though. Maybe it's the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)?

```js
class Foo {
  init() {
    console.log("A");
    console.log("B");
    this.doX();
    console.log("C");
  }
  doX(){}
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  doX() {
    console.log("X");
  }
}

new Bar().init();
```

Comment: Nice. But I can't see a way to access local variables of `init` inside `doX`. Any ideas on that matter? (passing as parameters and `return` is limited and you have to update superclass for subclass' every new need)

Comment: @user3702014 You can pass the relevant variables to doX, but you cannot modify them this way. If you have such a complex function I would consider to extract the whole functionality into a new class (with fields being the current local variables). If you give us more context we might propose solutions that matches your needs better